# Trouble with .htaccess and Two Files in Directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with my .htaccess file when trying to execute a different file in the same folder based on an extra URL parameter for an automobile website. I'm terrible at regex and really tried to get this working, hope you guys can help.

The directory structure is www.domain.com/car/make/model

My current .htaccess file lives in /car and is the following for the "make":

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !make\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]+)/([^/]+)
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|png|css)$ make.php?make=%2 [L]
```

This works fine for say www.domain.com/car/honda

When I try to add a new condition and rule above this one for the automobile "model", the rule doesn't fire for the request_uri (it keeps running make.php instead):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !model.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/])
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|png|css)$ model.php?test=%2&model=%3 [L]
```

I'm trying to execute a different file (model.php) for, say www.domain.com/car/honda/accord

What am I missing? Hope this makes sense. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /car/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ make.php?make=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ model.php?test=$1&model=$2 [L,QSA]
```